# Is it undefined behavior to have an index out of range for multi-dimension array?

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array

I know that using indexes those are out of range for arrays cause Undefined behavior.

But what about multi-dimension arrays this way:

```
int aa[][2]{ {5,7}, {23, 16}, {81, 83} };
    cout << aa[0][0] << endl;
    cout << (*aa)[0] << endl;
    cout << aa[0][1] << endl;
    cout << (*aa)[1] << endl;
    cout << aa[0][2] << endl; // here
    cout << (*aa)[2] << endl; // and here
```

- Above the array `aa`is an array for 3 arrays of 2 integers. So the Column size is 2. So the index should be in range : `0-->1` but when I used `aa[0][2]` I get `23` and not an undefined behavior?

Comment: "but when I used aa[0][2] I get 23 and not an undefined behavior? " - no, you get undefined behaviour. Which may mean your program appears to "work".

Comment: I'm not sure what you expect when you say that you don't get undefined behavior. Undefined behavior could be anything from the code seems to work to sending a space rocker to the moon. It will not always give an error. It's undefined.

Comment: @NeilButterworth: Is this also UB: `cout << (*aa)[2] << endl;`?

Comment: yes, `aa[0][2]` and `(*aa)[2]` are UB

Comment: @M.M: Thank you. Got it now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, the result you see is **because** your compiler utilizes the UB, when you access the array out of bounds.

When you access your variable via `aa[i][j]`, the compiler calculates the accessed address as follows (C uses [row-major-order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row-_and_column-major_order) memory layout):

```
address_of(aa)+2*i+j  # 2 elements in a row
```

But what if `i` or/and `j` are out of range? What should the compiler do?

If it weren't UB, the compiler would have to emit some code which checks the ranges and throws an error if ranges were violated.

Yet because this case **is** UB, the resulting program is allowed to do anything it likes:

- formating your hard disc
- send embarassing messages from your accounts
- crash
- just apply the above formula

the easies way for a compiler-programmer is to choose the last option, which is the case for all compilers I know (but you have no right to assume that this will be the case in the future - maybe a mean compiler-programmer will choose one of the first two options!).

With the above formula, the address of `aa[0][2]` is the same as for `aa[1][0]` (i.e. offset `2`), which explains the results you see.

Comment: Compilers that reformat your hard disk to punish you for coding errors are the absolute worst :)